# Time difference in hours and minutes from two times fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two input type time fields were selected as a class start and class end time. Here is the code of jquery where the difference of two times.

```
$('#class_end').on('change',function() 
    {
        var start_time = $('#class_strt').val();
        var end_time = $('#class_end').val();
        var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        $('#duration_id').val(diff);

    });
```

the issue is that it only gives an hour value, not minutes value, e.g., the user a select a classstart **12:00** and classend **13:00** it gives a **1** only and when user change a classend **13:30** then gives a **1.5**

I want this way select a classstart **12:00** and classend **13:00** then show like **01:00** and change a classend **13:30** then show a **01:30** and again change a classend **13:45** then show a **01:45**

Here is the HTML code

```
<td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                    Start Time
                    </label>
                    <input id="class_strt" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_strt">
                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                    End Time
                    </label>
                    <input id="class_end" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_end">
                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                     Duration
                     </label>
                        <input id="duration_id" type="text" name="duration_id">

                  </td>
```

Comment: can you please add  your html code?

Comment: ok just a minute

Comment: `strt` != `start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate difference in minutes only and then convert minutes into hour and minutes again. See below code

```js
$(function(){
$('#class_end').on('change',function() 
    {
        var start_time = $('#class_strt').val();
        var end_time = $('#class_end').val();
        var diff = (new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) /1000/60;
        var hour = parseInt(diff/60);
        var min = diff%60;
        if(min<10){
           min = "0" + min;
        }
        alert(hour + ":" + min);

    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="class_strt">
<input id="class_end">
```

Comment: @Arslan Time picker already works for you, it's about the calculation, just combine the two

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toISOString()` to than easily get the already formatted time.

```js
$('.timepicker').on('change', function() {

  var start = new Date("1970-1-1 " + $('#class_strt').val())
  var end = new Date("1970-1-1 " + $('#class_end').val());
  
  var diff = new Date(end - start).toISOString(); // "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.zzzZ"
  var hms = diff.match(/T([\d:]+)\./)[1].split(':'); // Get time and split by `:`
  
  $('#duration_id').val( hms[0] +':'+ hms[1] ); // Use hours [0] and minutes [1] 

});
```

```html
<label>Start Time</label>
<input id="class_strt" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_strt">

<label>End Time</label>
<input id="class_end" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_end">

<label>Duration</label>
<input id="duration_id" type="text" name="duration_id">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shortest answer. Good!

Comment: Nice one! toISOString and regex match!

Answer (score 0):

You can tranform the difference in minutes and create a "label":

```
$('#class_end').on('change',function() 
{

  var t = diff * 60;
  var hours = Math.floor(t/60);
  var minutes = t%60;
  $('#duration_id).val((hours < 10 ? '0' : '')+hours+":"+(minutes < 10 ? '0' : '')+minutes);

});
```

you can avoid the t variable by not dividing diff by the last 60

```
$('#class_end').on('change',function() 
{

  var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60;
  var hours = Math.floor(diff/60);
  var minutes = diff%60;
  $('#duration_id).val((hours < 10 ? '0' : '')+hours+":"+(minutes < 10 ? '0' : '')+minutes);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the difference in minute first and then find the Hours & Minutes from that.

```js
$('#class_end').on('change', function() {
  var start_time = $('#class_strt').val();
  var end_time = $('#class_end').val();
  var diff = (new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time)) / 1000 / 60; //difference in minutes
  var Hr = Math.floor(Number(diff) / 60); //Hour part
  var Min = Number(diff) % 60; //Minute part
  Min = ("0" + Min).slice(-2);
  $('#duration_id').val(Hr + " : " + Min);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="input-field col s1">
  <label>
                    Start Time
                    </label>
  <input id="class_strt" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_strt">
</td>
<td class="input-field col s1">
  <label>
                    End Time
                    </label>
  <input id="class_end" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_end">
</td>
<td class="input-field col s1">
  <label>
                     Duration
                     </label>
  <input id="duration_id" type="text" name="duration_id">

</td>
```